# Spacer overlay not showing if conditionally rendered

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to go from 2 columns to 3 columns if in landscape mode.

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ItemView()
            ItemView()
            ItemView()
        }
    }
}

struct ItemView: View {
    @Environment(\.verticalSizeClass) var verticalSizeClass: UserInterfaceSizeClass?
    @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) var horizontalSizeClass: UserInterfaceSizeClass?
    
    
    var body: some View {
        let isLandscape = verticalSizeClass == .compact
        
        HStack{
            Spacer()
                .overlay(Text("Column 1"), alignment: .leading)
            Text("Column 2") // centered
            if(isLandscape){
                Spacer()
                    .overlay(Text("Column 3"), alignment: .trailing)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SwiftUIView_Previews2: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIView()
    }
}
```

When I "Preview On Device" and rotate my iPhone, "Column 3" doesn't show up but there is spacing. This doesn't happen without the `if(isLandscape)`. I am not sure what the cause could be.

[image: iPhone screenshot]

Edit: I am using an iPhone SE with iOS 15.7.7.

Edit 2: There is a problem with the list styling when using iPadOS 16.5.1.

[image: line not showing]

(removing the `if isLandscape`)

[image: problem with first column]

(going from landscape to portrait, the second column doesn't have an underline)

[image: portrait]

Comment: The code is correct and working on iPhone 14 Pro. It may be related to the selected device. Also, I suggest to check for available width instead of the orientation.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini Using a hard-coded value like 500 and a `GeometryReader { proxy in proxy.size.width }` ?

Comment: you can calculate the size and see if there is enough space for desired number of items. for example you can set a minimum size for each item and divide the width to that value. Also, it seems you need a `grid` instead of `list`